# Getting element Id Sweet Alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, sweetalert

I'm trying to use [sweet alert](http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/) as a dialog to confirm the deletion of an entry on a table. 
There's a column on each table row which has a button which opens a 'Sweet Alert' confirm dialog.

The code of my table is as follow:

```
<tr>
    <!-- Other Table Colums -->
    <td>
    <button userid="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" id="<?php echo('bn_delete_' . $row['id']); ?>" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs warning-message-parameter">Delete</button>
    <td>
 </tr>
```

The code for my sweet alert dialog is:

```
swal({   title: "Are you sure?",   
         text: "You will not be able to recover this imaginary file!", 
         type: "warning",   showCancelButton: true,   confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",   
         confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",   
         closeOnConfirm: false }, 
         function(){   
               swal("Deleted!", "Your imaginary file has been deleted.", "success"); });
```

When the user clicks yes on the dialog, I want to get the id of the button which the user just clicked. That way I'll be able to get the value of the attribute userid which I can then use to delete the entry from database.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the id of the clicked button by retrieving it when the button is clicked, and passing it as a parameter to the plugin callback.
Take a look at the following implementation:

```
$('#openSwal').on('click', function(e) {

  var id = $(e.currentTarget).attr("id"); 
  var userId = $(e.currentTarget).data("user-id"); 

  var region = "myregion";

  swal({
    html: true,
    title: '' + region,
    showCancelButton: true,
    showConfirmButton: true,
    confirmButtonText: "save", 
    text: "<span onclick='save()'>l</span>"

  }, function() { 
    save(id, userId);
  });

});

function save(id, userId) {
  console.log(id);
  console.log(userId); 
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jwsho9L9/4/