# Using Typed JS in a Sweetalert 2

Tags: javascript, sweetalert2, typed.js

How do i use a Typed JS in a sweetalert2 ? I tried this, of course it doesn't work `Swal.fire('Any fool can use a computer')`

Answer (score 0):

Try this one on getting sweet alert’s id.

Link: [Getting element Id Sweet Alert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35535774/getting-element-id-sweet-alert/35536091#35536091)

After grabbing swal’s id, pass it to Typed.js’s constructor with your preferred options.